# multiple data trigger conditions

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm not sure if what I'm trying to do is possible, but hopefully so.
I have a `TextBlock` that I'm trying to set styles based on multiple conditions.

Below is a simplified version of the xaml for example.

```
<Style.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="A" Value="False">
        <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    ...
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
        <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    ...
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
    </DataTrigger>
    <MultiDataTrigger>
        <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
            <Condition Binding="{Binding A}" Value="True"/>
            <Condition Binding="{Binding B}" Value="True"/>
        </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
        <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource DayBrush}"/>
            <Setter Property="Text" Value="..."/>
        </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
    </MultiDataTrigger>
    <MultiDataTrigger>
        <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
            <Condition Binding="{Binding A}" Value="True"/>
            <Condition Binding="{Binding B}" Value="False"/>
        </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
        <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource NightBrush}"/>
            <Setter Property="Text" Value="..."/>
        </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
    </MultiDataTrigger> 
</Style.Triggers>
```

The trigger that starts and stops the storyboard works fine, but the other triggers don't seem to work at all.

Basically there are 3 conditions.

> 1. A is false.
> 2. A is true and B is true.
> 3. A is true and B is false.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: conditions are set correctly. please show [mcve] - what is A and B?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I make a sample code, it works normally.
I put up the code on Github, so compare it with your code.
 **[Here](https://github.com/devncore/community/tree/main/stackoverflow/answers/textblock-trigger-sample)**

#### MainResource.xaml

```xml
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}" x:Key="IN.TEXT">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsAnimal}" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Text" Value="Who Am I?"/>
            <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="1" To="0"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
            <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
        </DataTrigger>
        <MultiDataTrigger>
            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Binding="{Binding IsAnimal}" Value="True"/>
                <Condition Binding="{Binding IsHuman}" Value="True"/>
            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
            <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
                <Setter Property="Text" Value="I'm human!"/>
            </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
        </MultiDataTrigger>
        <MultiDataTrigger>
            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Binding="{Binding IsAnimal}" Value="True"/>
                <Condition Binding="{Binding IsHuman}" Value="False"/>
            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
            <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Navy"/>
                <Setter Property="Text" Value="I'm not a human!"/>
            </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
        </MultiDataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0 20 0 0"/>
</Style>
```

#### Result

1. A is false. (Opacity of the text is being changed)
   [image]
   [image]
2. A is true and B is true.
   [image]
3. A is true and B is false.
   [image]

Comment: Thanks for the post. I'll mark your solution as the answer as it helped me figure out what was ACTUALLY going on. 

The real problem is that when the storyboard stopped on the data trigger exit action, it wasn't leaving the text box in the state I expected, based on the second property. Rather it was obviously just setting it to whatever was in the exit storyboard.

I ended up changing it so that the exit action just used RemoveStoryboard and that gave me the expected results.

Thanks again.